# header cart issue on multilingual site

Tags: commerce

I have a problem with my header cart which is a block showing how many product have been added to the cart.

In the default language the order proces works just fine.
However when I test the proces in another language there is a problem with the link of the header cart.

The link refers to the default language shopping cart form instead of the language the current page is.

When I manually add in the url the specific language (e.g. de/cart) it works just fine including the rest of the order process.

Does anyone know what the problem would be?